# How to create this array with PHP with foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Maybe I will try to ask you the opposite way.
I got always problems while creating an array with foreach Loops.

The array shall look like this:

```
$arr[0]['title'] = 'Title'; --> first foreach-loop
$arr[0]['title'][0]['data'] = 'Text'; --> second foreach-loop
```

But when I start to fill the second foreach Loop PHP throws an error:

```
Cannot use string offset as an array
```

I would like to have this result with my foreach but I can't find my Problem:

```
array(2) {
  ["fields"]=>
  array(32) {
    [0]=>
    string(10) "Background"
    ["Area"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["total"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "123"
        ["parent"]=>
        array(1) {
          [0]=>
          string(1) "0"
        }
      }
      ["land"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "456"
      }
      ["water"]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(3) "789"
      }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
I use the following to create my array:

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
  $arr[$i]['title'] = $node;
  // some if to select the important elements
  foreach ($subnodes as $j => $subnode) {
    $arr[$i]['title'][$j]['data'] = $subnode;
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the code you are using?

Comment: You can't assign a value to `$arr[0]['title']` and then assign a value to `$arr[0]['title'][0]['data']`. Replace `$arr[0]['title']` with `$arr[0]['title']['value']`. That should resolve the error.

Comment: @Singhal I've added my foreach loops

Comment: How about you post some of the data you're trying to read instead of how the array looks like, you're getting the data from some place, is it RSS? XML? can you provide more detail on the data you need to read and perhaps we can be more of help to you. Also the array you posted is incomplete you have 2 entries on it and yet only shows 1 of the entries, basically that is a bunch of arrays inside other arrays making a big multidimensional array, easy enough to recreate but without guidelines not worth it.

Comment: I really would like to post it, but at the Moment I can only print it on the Screen. It contains more then 500 rows of code. I use xPath to crawl over a Website and I'm able to view the results in the right order. But I want to save it into an array and later to write it in a database.
But I'm not sure if you really need the data. I posted one of my result that my foreach loop prints.

Answer (score 0):

If you start from the `fields` level, your third level key is not an integer :

```
array(2) {
  ["fields"]=> // ROOT LEVEL string
  array(32) {
    [0]=> // FIRST LEVEL int
    string(10) "Background"
    ["Area"]=> //SECOND LEVEL string
    array(3) {
      ["total"]=> //THIRD LEVEL string
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
       ....
```

Or you try to access with an integer key :

```
$arr[0] //FIRST LEVEL int
   ['title'] //SECOND LEVEL string
      [0] //THIRD LEVEL int <= here is the mismatch
        ['data'] = 'Text';
```

Comment: How can I try to Access when I'm unable to write/create first? :-(

Comment: Oh my bad. I don't start at the "fields" Level. I start at the first integer. In this case [0]. Yes you marked it as FIRST LEVEL.

Comment: So you have the solution ?

Comment: No I don't have. I got always the error while creating that array. :-(

Comment: What do you mean in your second box? You wrote *//THIRD LEVEL int <= here is the mismatch*
Is that [0] wrong?

Comment: Yes, you try to access with `0` instead of a string so you have this error

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code :

```
$arr = array();
foreach ($nodes as $i => $node) {
$arr[$i]['title'] = array();  
$arr[$i]['title']['value'] = $node;
  // some if to select the important elements
  foreach ($subnodes as $j => $subnode) {
    $arr[$i]['title'][$j] = array();
    $arr[$i]['title'][$j]['data'] = $subnode;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried it but unfortunately the last line
throws the same error again: Cannot use string offset as an array

Comment: Ehm? I just saw your code top. Why do you write 'value' in the first Loop and in the second Loop you use an integer?

Comment: @Tipo This is because PHP arrays actually associative maps. You can use an integer or string as key in the same array.